# И еще - о слове "строптивый"

Tags: этимология

Пока писала вопрос о норове, задумалась над словом "строптивый" - непокорный, норовистый. Интересно, а каково его происхождение? Это какой-то старославянский корень?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Шанского  это слово определяется как исконное, суф. производное от стръпът - упорство, упрямство,затруднение, помеха.

Родственными он считает слова "струна" и "струп", имеющие значение твердый, жесткий, настроенный, сравнить: struo (лат.) - прилаживаю, выстраиваю в порядок, stroum (др.-нем) - веревка.

Эти качества и лежат в основе характера строптивого человека -  упрямого, своевольного и непокорного. Образно говоря, строптивыми мы называем  "построенных" людей, "перестроить" которых очень трудно.

Answer (score 1):

Историко-этимологический словарь П.Я.Черных определяет слово как русское ( отмечается в древнерусском языке с 11-го века в значениях "лукавый","коварный" ). Производное  от  "стръпътъ" - труд, работа,  помеха.  В  старославянском  корень  не  отмечен.